# How can I display a character above U+FFFF?

Tags: unicode, processing

How can I display a character above U+FFFF? Say I want to show [U+1F384](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f384/index.htm). `"\u1F384"` is interpreted as `"\u1F38"` followed by the character `"4"`, and gives the error `No glyph found for the ? (\u1F38) character`. `"\uD83C\uDF84"` is interpreted as the character `"\uD83C"` followed by the character `"\uDF84"`, and gives the error

```
No glyph found for the ? (\uD83C) character
No glyph found for the ? (\uDF84) character
```

Here is some example code to demonstrate:

```java
PFont font;

void setup()
{
  size(128, 128);
  background(0);
  font = loadFont("Symbola-8.vlw");
  textFont(font, 8);

  fill(255);
  text("\u1F384", 10, 10);

}

void draw()
{

}
```

As stated by the tag, this is in the language [Processing](http://processing.org).
`\U0001F384` gives the error `unexpected char: 'U'`, presumably because processing doesn't support UTF-32 in that format.

It doesn't really matter *how* it is displayed, the main problem is making a string contain a character whose decimal codepoint is greater than 65,535.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: @bmargulies Processing, as stated by the [processing] tag.

Comment: You need to specify your programming language. For example, in C#, [you can use `\U########`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Figure out how to do UTF32 encoding in your platform; I could not find any information with a quick search (processing.org server seemed unreachable for me).

Comment: It doesn't know how to deal properly with utf-16 surrogates.  That isn't that unusual, a magic fix tends to be hard to come by.  Yeah, that site is down hard, bad timing.

Comment: The `\u` escape is followed by exactly 4 hexadecimal digits. In C++ at least there's also a `\U` escape that takes eight hexadecimal digits and so works for codepoints outside the BMP.

Comment: @bames53 As I said before, "`\U0001F384` gives the error `unexpected char: 'U'`, presumably because processing doesn't support UTF-32 in that format."

Comment: Even Java doesn't support `\U`, so I wouldn't be surprised if a simplified derivative doesn't. Java also doesn't support hex escapes in strings. It looks to me like Processing simply doesn't support Unicode well enough to enable non-BMP characters.

Comment: If this is Processing, why is there a [tag:java] tag?

Comment: @Јοеу http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251014/2846923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `'\u{1F384}'` in ECMASCript 6 compatible browser.